# How to avoid Android application UI changes on low battery level?

Tags: android, user-interface, batterylevel

I'm developing an Android application according to provided UI. The UI is in bright colors and everything works well.
But when the battery level goes low the battery saver regime turns on and the UI in my application turns dark and some texts become unreadable
Is there any way to avoid it? I see that, for example, Facebook app is not changing its UI during battery saving process.
Thanks in advance.
Provided two screenshots in regular and saving mode:
[image: regular mode]

[image: battery saver mode]